# Computational geometry exercises

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples, book-recommendation, computational-geometry

Does anyone know of a book, website etc. that has exercises with solutions for computational geometry? I'm reading a book **Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications**, which has exercises, but no solutions for them. If there are solution for the exercises in this book, it would be even better!